# Did %pip install on VertexAI notebook, how to 'reset' conda/base?

Tags: python, conda, environment, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I've finally bothered to look into environments and whatnot - I've always worked on my local machine and installed everything to base because I didn't know better.

Now in VertexAI notebook for work, I've done several %pip installs and I think my base env is full of user-installed packages. No issues right now, but I need suggestions on how to 'reset' my notebook so that I can setup a (python 3.8) env to work with.

I've looked into resetting conda/base for my local machine and found answers on conda install --rev 1 or --rev 0 which are risky. I've always ended up doing fresh installs (this last time I just went with mambaforge).

With VertexAI I guess there's no anaconda, but it does use conda. I just don't know what the equivalent of fresh install would be, other than creating a new notebook and copy/pasting all my stuff over.

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps looking for [this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/managed/create-managed-notebooks-instance-console-quickstart#reset_your_instance)? This is a step on how to initialize the VM's memory content to its initial state.

Or one possible workaround I see is listing the user installed packages and uninstalling it

`pip freeze --user | xargs pip uninstall -y`

This option is also viable, migrating your files to a new notebook instead.

> other than creating a new notebook and copy/pasting all my stuff over.

Comment: I think 'reset' option is more like shutting down jupyter lab and re-starting it, but I'm not too certain.

Will look into the pip freeze command - usually these approaches to 'find non-default packages in base' don't pan out for me and I end up reinstalling anaconda (which in this case would be the copy/pasting approach)

As an example I'm currently also cleaning my work PC and running `conda env export --from-history` led to things like anaconda-client, conda, conda-build, console_shortcut, etc to be included. Not sure why.